Using a Raspberry Pi Pico on a motorcycle lights/blinkers: how to power and use I/O?
I'd like to build a "smart" blinker for my old motorcycle, as the original one can't handle LED bulbs (not enough power consumption) and also i want to increase functionality.
It should keep on DRL LED lights and when the left, right or the emergency blinker commands are engaged, turn the DRL off and make the yellow lamps blinks.
So it should be able to take the existing command as inputs, and have some outputs.
I'm an electrotechnician and a programmer, but not an electronic; i'm able to solder and build circuits, but not to invent them. What I don't know is how to handle the noisy, rippled 12 to 14V of the bike in order to give to the Raspberry the clean Power he needs and also how to make it able to get inputs and manage outputs. And this all also needs to be as small as possible.
Maybe 'cause i'm not a native english speaker, i may lack the right words and by searching the web i always find tutorial for build "Carputers", but it is not what i need.

your question is not specific to the Raspberry Pi ... almost any microcontroller would require clean power

Could you clarify what DRL is - or means?

@Seamus: Daylight Running Light. I learned it from US forum/youtube channels and i thought it was a widely accepted acronym like LED. Sorry for not have been clear.

I think the 'Pico' microcontroller is a reasonably good choice for your application:

inexpensive
"rugged" - as compared to the pampered Raspberry Pi SBCs
supports a range of input power voltages (not the RP2040 chip itself, but Pico (the board) has an in-built regulator)
C/C++ and Python (micro-Python) supported as development languages
Also supported by Arduino's development environment (via the Philhower package; aka arduino-pico)

It seems to me that your hardware challenges will come primarily from two sources:

Powering the Pico from the 12-14 V motorcycle battery

The electrical interface between the Pico's GPIO and the lights (LEDs, etc)


I'll attempt to address these two hardware challenges in the sequel:
Powering the Pico from a 12-14 V motorcycle battery
You may wish to peruse the Pico datasheet while reading this.
The RPi Pico has an in-built regulator that accommodates input power in the range of 1.8V - 5.5V. And so, another (external) regulator will be needed to bring your motorcycle's electrical system voltage down to a voltage the Pico can tolerate. This regulator can be quite small (low-powered, inexpensive) because the Pico does not use much power itself.
I have come to favor the regulators built by Pololu for my projects because they are inexpensive, and perform well. In your application, I think I would go with a (nominal) 3.3V regulator; specifically this one. Note that the specifications for this regulator include an input voltage range of 4 V – 50 V; that should cover the variability/transients from your M/C electrical system.
This is shown below in the schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Interfacing the Pico's GPIO w/ the 12-14 V electrical system
Because the Pico's GPIO pins are electrically fragile, they must be buffered from the devices they control. Otherwise, they will evaporate as soon as they are connected! There are many ways to buffer a GPIO pin. Since your question is not specific in this regard, I'll cover one general way to buffer GPIO that will (hopefully) work reasonably well for several types of devices. We will illustrate buffering using a bipolar, NPN, Darlington pair transistor.
I have chosen bipolar transistors for their low input voltage interface, the Darlington configuration for its current gain, and NPN for ease of interface to low-side switching. You may find that you will not need the Darlington for all interfaces; a single transistor may work fine. We can address these specifics through new, specific questions when they arise.
All that said, the schematic below shows how a single interface between the Pico and a motorcycle flasher LED might be designed. I have chosen this LED to illustrate the design; it's specifications are here. N.B.: Please don't take this as a recommendation of any sort as I have ZERO experience with automotive flashers!

simulate this circuit
What you'll discover later - after you gain some experience with electronic design - is that the TIP 120 Darlington is a lot more transistor than you probably need for this particular LED. I chose it b/c it's a reasonable choice for this application (and to keep in your parts bin!), it will handle more powerful LEDs and it's a versatile transistor.

Many, many thanks for this detailed answer. I'll need time to understand, digest and learn what you told me but in general makes sense to me, so i am confidend. The only thing missing is how to read an input from the bike; seems to me that it is a sort of "reverse" application of the transistor logic, but i have to sort it out. But what bother me is from the 3.2. General purpose I/O chapter from the Pico datasheet (which is too long to quote here) about applying power to inputs before the Pico is powered (and i'm not sure that this can't happens when i turn the bike ignition key)

@Parduz: Here's the paragraph that addresses your concern: GPIO 26-29 are ADC-capable and have an internal reverse diode to the VDDIO (3.3V) rail, so the input voltage must not exceed VDDIO plus about 300mV. If the RP2040 is unpowered, applying a voltage to these GPIO pins will 'leak' through the diode into the VDDIO rail. GPIO pins 0-25 (and the debug pins) do not have this restriction and therefore voltage can safely be applied to these pins when RP2040 is unpowered up to 3.3V. In other words, the warning ONLY APPLIES to the ADC input GPIOs. AFAIK, you're not using them, so no worry.

Accepting the answer: could you show in your answer how to read an input from the bike? that's the only part "missing" from the original question. About the ADC Inputs: thanks for your patience; i totally missed it was only for the analog ones.

@Parduz: That would probably best be handled as a separate question.

Use a DC/DC module and a smoothing capacitor on the DC/DC input.
Most electronic shops (IRL or internet) has DC/DC modules that should fit your needs.
Example could be the DC360 module or a LM2596 based module.
